# Replace commas in string C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
select name,lastname,email from contacts
```

I want to replace the commas for **+"|"+**
 and get something like this

```
select name+"|"+lastname+"|"+email from contacts
```

thats easy with  string.Replace(",",+"|"+);

but the problem is when i face a string like this:

```
select name,lastname,isnull(email,0) from contacts
```

How i cant detect to avoid the commas inside the isnull()?
with the replace i get a string like this

```
select name+"|"+lastname+"|"+isnull(email+"|"+0) from contacts
```

and thats wrong!

thanks .

Comment: what regex's have you tried?

Comment: Regex maybe? Or perhaps split the string, taking the isnull out, performing your replace, and joining the string back together

Comment: You need to write a state machine that loops through the characters keeping track of the parenthesis and determines if the comma should be replaced.

Comment: "That's easy with (code that wouldn't compile)" doesn't help much... it would be better if you would provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem... not that I'm really sure that doing this kind of replace on a SQL query is a very good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write your own method:

```
private static string replace_commas(String str_)
{
    StringBuilder str = new System.Text.StringBuilder(str_);

    bool replace = true;

    for(int i = 0; i != str.Length; ++i)
    {
        if(str[i] == ',' && replace)
            str[i] = '|';

        if(str[i] == '(')
        {
            replace = false;
            continue;
        }

        if(str[i] == ')' && !replace)
            replace = true;
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

You fill in the blanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks!!!!  works like charm!!, now  i can detect the sintax that i want to avoid

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static string ReplaceTopLevelCommas(string query)
{
    var newQuery = new StringBuilder();
    var level = 0;

    foreach (var c in query)
    {
        if (c == ',')
        {
            if (level == 0)
            {
                newQuery.Append("+\"|\"+");
            }
            else
            {
                newQuery.Append(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == '(')
            {
                level++;
            }
            else if (c == ')')
            {
                level--;
            }

            newQuery.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return newQuery.ToString();
}
```

It replaces commas only if they're not inside any parentheses. So it will also work for multiple levels of nesting.

Working example: http://ideone.com/TGPRe2

Comment: Thanks!!, I really appreciate your help